# Creating an image feed from another URL

Tags: javascript, html, magento

First off, forgive me if this sounds stupid, I'll try to explain the best I can. From what I've gathered, I *think* this is like an RSS feed but I'm not 100% sure if what I'm asking is doable.

So say I have a website. Website.com and on my home page I have a div with 'Pictures' with an image as the banner. Then I have a different page, website.com/images and on /images I have a set of pictures I upload to daily. Is it possible to link these two pages together so that whatever new picture I put up on /images automatically sets the banner for the home page div?

I know I can hard code the image in but just seeing if this is doable.

```
<div class="medium-grid flex-column">
        <a class="ab-feat ab-fade height-fix" href="/url!!">
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Images</h3>
                <p>Some random text for now</p>
            </div>
            <div class="img-cover">
                <img src="url/for/banner.jpg" alt="images" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us the code that you have already on the first page. Also, will you always control both pages, or could they be completely different websites?

Comment: Broad. At the most basic level, you _could_ simply use the same `filename` each time you upload and that's all there is to it. If it's going to be some dynamic way of figuring out "which among x in `/images`" then "how" becomes too broad. The quick answer is Yes of course it can be done.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I edited my main post to show it. I have control of both pages.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload images on the `website.com/images`, you should save the images url in your database. so that you will be able to get the latest image url from the database and set it as banner on the `website.com`

You can create a database table `images`

```
images - id
       - url
       - created_at
```

`html`

```
<div class="banner">

</div>
```

`javascript`

```
$.get('url/to/get/latest/image', function (response) {
  $('.banner').css('background-image', response.body.img.src);
});
```

or if you receive an array of all the images use this

```
$.get('url/to/get/all/images', function (response) {
  $('.banner').css('background-image', response.body.images[images.length -1].src); // use (images.length -1) to have the index of the latest image
});
```

Comment: That's kinda what I meant by hard coding the image in. I know that when I upload the image there, I can just change the image URL on the banner itself so it shows the correct one. I'm more just looking to skip that step and let me upload to one page without having to touch the other. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: You will not be the one to change the image src of the banner. but banner images src will be set to the latest image from the db

Comment: Oh okay. But this is using php it looks like?

Comment: I edited my answer. have a look pls.

Comment: It's as simple as that? And in that it just knows to pull the last known uploaded image?

Comment: yes, as for my latest edit, you just need to know how to pull the latest image uploaded, or even all the images uploaded. So that you can decide on which image to put as banner.

Comment: One more stupid question. Does it matter where I put the javascript code in the main page? Or should it go within the div container?

Comment: You can put it a either an external javascript file or within the main html file using the `<script>` tag. But your javascript should be wrapped within a `document.ready` function. So that script will wait until the dom is rendered before trying to access it.

Comment: okay thank you. I'll test it out tomorrow!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163061/discussion-between-brandon-and-kamga-simo-junior).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. If you are using WordPress, it has an easy way to create an [RSS feed](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds). You will need to create your "images" RSS feed and publish it. This will give you a unique URL that your main page can "subscribe" to. Then, on your main page, you will have to create some mechanism to refresh data from that URL. The easiest way would be to create a polling mechanism that polls that URL and updates your `div`

If you are not using WordPress, most CMS's have something similar built in. Just search their documentation for RSS feeds.

If you are not using any CMS, this is still doable, but you will have to code everything yourself.

Comment: I use Magento which I don't think has this built in, at least not this version. But I guess that confirms it's an RSS thing I have to do.